# How do I calculate the residue of $\sin(z+1/z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

How do I do this about $\displaystyle z=0$ ?.

I tried creating a Laurent expansion and extracting it from there but I wasn't sure how to isolate the $\displaystyle 1/z$ expression.
$$
\mbox{I got}\quad \left(\, z + {1 \over z}\,\right)
-{1 \over 6}\left(\, z + {1 \over z}\,\right)^{3} + \cdots
$$

Any help is appreciated !.

Comment: It is not difficult to find the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ in $(z+z^{-1})^{2k+1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coefficient of $1/z$ in  $z+\frac1{z}$ is $1$.

The coefficient of of $1/z$ in $\left ( z+\frac1{z}\right )^3 = 3$

In general, the coefficient of $1/z$ in $\left ( z+\frac1{z}\right )^{2 k+1}$ may be found from the expansion

$$\left ( z+\frac1{z}\right )^{2 k+1} = z^{2 k+1} + \binom{2 k+1}{1} z^{2 k-1} + \cdots +\binom{2 k+1}{k+1} \frac1{z} + \cdots \frac1{z^{2 k+1}} $$

so really, we want the sum

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2 k+1)!} \binom{2 k+1}{k+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k! (k+1)!} = J_1(2)$$

where $J_1$ is the Bessel function of the first kind of first order.

Comment: Thanks! That was a lot more complicated than I thought it would be..found that question on an old final and got stuck!

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

> The residue of $\ds{\sin\pars{z + {1 \over z}}}$ is given by:

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\,{\rm Res}_{z\ =\ 0}\pars{\sin\pars{z + {1 \over z}}}}\ =\
\overbrace{\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}\sin\pars{z + {1 \over z}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}^{\dsc{z}\ \ds{\equiv}\ \dsc{\expo{\ic\theta}}}
\\[5mm]&={1 \over 2\pi}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin\pars{2\cos\pars{\theta}}\expo{\ic\theta}\,\dd\theta
={1 \over \pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin\pars{2\cos\pars{\theta}}\cos{\theta}\,\dd\theta
=\color{#66f}{\large\,{\rm J}_{1}\pars{2}}\approx{\tt 0.5767}
\end{align}

> $\ds{\,{\rm J}_{\nu}}$ is a [Bessel Function of the First Kind](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_360.htm).

Comment: Very cool approach!

Comment: @User38 I'm glad you found it useful. Thanks.